# Tab max width percentage screen

Tags: android

Hello I need set a maxwidth to my tabs, but it is not a fix size it is going to be a porcentage of screen then I supose that I have to do it programmatically, but I not have idea how can I do it. Any help? thank you

Edit: I don't know how much tabs I have to draw, I get it from a service

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created a custom view for my tab and calculate and set the screen porcentage programmatically

```
private void setTabView(List<String> rowList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowList.size(); i++) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_item, null);
        TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_tab);
        tv.setText(rowList.get(i));
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        tv.setMaxWidth(((int) (width * MAX_TAB_SIZE_PORCENT)));
        try {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(view);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.tag(TAG).i(e);
        }
    }
}
```

custom_tab_item is just a TextView

hope help :)